# Как сделать скролл определенного блока, но на всем экране?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок со стилем overflow-y: auto, весь контент страницы вмещается в экран. Весь скролл проиходит в блоке поменьше, там весь контент. Необходимо, чтобы в любой точке документа при скролле скролился этот блок.
P.S. Для тех кто не может понять что я имею ввиду. Мне нужны не события мыши типа wheel и scroll.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно как раз событие `wheel`.
Без прокрутки документа посмотрите [тут](https://codepen.io/rf150rus/pen/YvjEyy)

```js
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  document.getElementById('block').scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('block').scrollTop + e.deltaY);
}, true);
```

```css
#block {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam amet sit autem itaque porro quisquam consequatur odio temporibus necessitatibus vitae eligendi ullam magni, excepturi iusto, officia mollitia, voluptates reprehenderit. Quaerat? Error,
  ratione itaque libero maxime nemo neque eligendi doloribus dolor voluptatem, corrupti earum qui cum tempora ullam fugiat reprehenderit ipsa illo. Ducimus eius repellendus atque quas animi quod, inventore tempora. Aspernatur voluptate ab quaerat nostrum
  numquam corrupti non, quas magnam impedit. Itaque aliquam libero dolor pariatur mollitia ratione assumenda deleniti tempora nisi facere voluptates aspernatur doloribus quisquam, quos provident sint? Doloribus quasi, corporis maiores in, molestias repellendus
  quaerat possimus ea voluptatibus necessitatibus repellat ullam! Est perspiciatis similique labore culpa quam! Vitae eius cum hic quo sunt, culpa deserunt ullam quisquam. Voluptatum optio est facere dolorem excepturi doloribus consectetur, sapiente expedita
  ipsum dolorum? Ea voluptatibus tempore cumque, blanditiis, reprehenderit sit maxime facere amet rerum laboriosam magnam iusto quasi soluta id quam. Vero et nam molestiae neque beatae impedit perspiciatis animi deserunt, dolorem, reprehenderit quas dolores
  sint assumenda. Voluptas veritatis cum minima quis delectus eaque magni nihil error, ad asperiores doloremque vero. Alias, sequi perferendis quisquam non tenetur optio asperiores deserunt iusto nisi eaque, vitae impedit ex ipsa quidem minus officiis!
  Quibusdam, odit voluptate. Dicta, ipsum? Provident fugiat magni neque et expedita? Dolorem repellendus nisi unde dolore error asperiores laudantium impedit culpa atque velit, blanditiis libero iste fuga dignissimos quam totam quibusdam illo minima nobis
  doloremque. Excepturi recusandae fugit dolore culpa quod. Commodi quidem ducimus explicabo. Ad nesciunt cupiditate inventore velit fuga est molestiae modi, maiores id ducimus excepturi nostrum dignissimos, deleniti libero nulla sunt nihil non quod tempora
  alias eius voluptatum! Voluptates voluptate rem reprehenderit tempora maxime, vero beatae distinctio cum, omnis asperiores nisi, quibusdam amet. Consequatur, quis ipsam autem perspiciatis odit unde fugit sint dolorum quaerat, nulla ad. Id, cumque! Vitae
  reprehenderit ratione, corporis dolor aliquid quos quasi voluptas quisquam corrupti nisi accusamus tenetur quod, natus cum dolorum iste maiores, explicabo recusandae eligendi dolorem? Nemo amet dolores perspiciatis! Minima, nostrum. Veritatis maiores
  quod vel laudantium pariatur ea cumque harum, esse tenetur. Dolorem adipisci repellendus quidem fugiat fugit eveniet esse velit itaque quaerat dicta incidunt, debitis fuga voluptatum odit alias reprehenderit. Delectus deserunt officia amet, quos, saepe
  molestias consectetur et optio quam ea veritatis repellendus quae ex facilis distinctio impedit, perferendis doloribus tenetur ipsum eveniet. Quaerat nostrum error ratione labore dignissimos? Totam inventore pariatur, sint esse nihil adipisci nesciunt
  magnam consequuntur illo illum repellat amet reprehenderit. Ullam est numquam suscipit nemo voluptas dolor doloribus neque ipsa! Fuga accusantium dicta ad ducimus? Hic, saepe! Corporis ut perferendis suscipit maxime nobis accusantium quasi eos? Sequi
  saepe quis consequatur molestias optio sed, officia dolorum architecto pariatur sint fugit, eos minima natus porro aspernatur sit. Vero, magnam architecto iusto ducimus enim a earum delectus pariatur qui unde fugit inventore distinctio sapiente porro
  repellat quo odio deserunt quisquam ipsum quidem repudiandae molestias asperiores? At, eaque officiis. Inventore mollitia aspernatur aliquid amet alias quos molestias. Est, repellat facere doloremque dicta quidem nobis reiciendis odit labore expedita
  unde impedit dignissimos ipsum fugit qui in commodi tempore cum nemo. Tempore consequatur doloremque quia odio, aspernatur eveniet consequuntur facere impedit doloribus accusamus sed, architecto reiciendis amet iusto sint tenetur aperiam veniam? Porro
  cumque ea ullam corporis inventore velit sapiente totam? Quia vero officia eveniet illum reprehenderit alias tempore est dolorem sunt ipsum dolorum, laudantium neque quis ad saepe repellat excepturi vel quae delectus consequatur odit fugiat omnis a
  necessitatibus. Ipsum. Ratione vero tenetur esse unde eos dolorum perspiciatis consequuntur ut, neque qui dolor est sequi, itaque perferendis eius. Quo exercitationem sint nisi provident suscipit laudantium numquam odit unde fugiat doloribus? Temporibus
  esse aperiam accusamus, ipsam eveniet dolor minus ipsum illum laudantium eaque obcaecati natus unde tempora libero nesciunt iste quia quos rem sapiente debitis harum fugit. Quasi obcaecati labore fugiat. Cupiditate alias veritatis quasi facere aliquid
  adipisci doloribus sapiente, culpa autem ipsum consequatur dolor voluptates! Exercitationem sit minus laborum debitis ut impedit illum porro rerum, aperiam reprehenderit quam modi tenetur? Excepturi eos tempore facere voluptatem voluptatum impedit voluptates
  officiis expedita dolorem cum velit maxime, iste voluptas necessitatibus quas minus pariatur blanditiis odio omnis similique quasi obcaecati. Temporibus ex eveniet pariatur? Dignissimos, corrupti voluptatum officiis voluptates nihil consectetur illum
  magni, iste ipsum eos soluta nostrum nesciunt molestias reprehenderit blanditiis optio laboriosam, quo eligendi quod consequuntur corporis exercitationem adipisci veritatis? Quaerat, eaque. Adipisci architecto obcaecati fuga corporis autem necessitatibus
  tempora sapiente quam suscipit vitae error cum minus reiciendis ab, quaerat, laudantium provident animi facere? Hic corporis ad repellat aliquid culpa odit illum.
</div>
```